# how to get webview to work in dart

Tags: webview, dart

I want to use the webview tag in a chrome packaged app written in Dart,

I try to get the browser example inside the webview package to work

https://github.com/HannesRammer/webview

but when I set the webview attribute 'src', or call a function like 'back' using the jsinterop, it tells me unknown method back ... as far as I can see the package uses the correct jsinterop calls

maybe webview is not proper supported by jsObject, or what am I missing out ??

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are running it as a Chrome App (right-click on the `manifest.json` in the Dart Editor and select "run as Chrome App").  The errors you describe sound like what you would see in a web app context, where the Chrome APIs are not available... also check that you have the `webview` permission in the `manifest.json` file.